# How to include one html file into other html file in dreamweaver

Tags: html

Please tell me how i include html page (e.g. a.html) into other html page (e.g. b.html).

I have tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(function(){
 $("#header").load("header.html");
 });
</script>
```

but this does not work. Please tell me another one.

Comment: Are you running under a web server (http://) or a folder (file://)

Comment: I am running under a web server but i have also tried this with folder (file://) also.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use the <frameset>.

<frameset cols="*,*">
  <frame src="frame_a.htm">
  <frame src="frame_b.htm">
</frameset>
```

if you are using HTML5 try the

```
<iframe>
```

the example for iframe is,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Frames Test</title>
<style>
 .menu {
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  height:80%;
}
.mainContent {
  float:left;
  width:75%;
  height:80%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe class="menu" src="a.html"></iframe>
<iframe class="mainContent" src="b.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

you can find more about iframe in the following link,

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: frameset is supported on html5.

Comment: I mean to say frameset is not supported in html5.

Comment: Hi I have tried iframe but this not works properly in browsers.

Comment: Will you please tell how to use bootstrap because  i am working on dreamweaver.

Comment: download the bootstrap3 library files(.js) from http://getbootstrap.com/       , follow the instructions given in the getting started section. dreamweaver is the best tool for using bootstrap in your html code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that you are including jquery as a library on the page into which you are importing. Additionally the header must have an ID of header.

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#header").load("b.html");
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 
  <body>
    <div id="header">
    </div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Ya, I am including this jquery-1.11.0.js library on the page but this does not works in Google chrome browser.

Comment: Is there any output in the JavaScript console? Also any chance you could update the question with more information like the rest of the HTML file? Finally is the second file on your local filesystem as JQuery has a same origin policy This works perfectly in IE11 for me.